# UnityDependencyResolver can't resolve Enum

Tags: .net, unity-container

I work with .Net Framework 4.7 and `UnityDependencyResolver`. My customer write a constructor with an Enum as the parameter and `UnityDependencyResolver` cannot initialize this constructor.

I guess the Enum parameter is the cause of the problem. I tried to search using the keyword "UnityDependencyResolver can't resolve Enum", but couldn't find any explanation.

Can someone give me accurate information or a satisfactory explanation? Look forward to the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's been so long ago since I wrote [Dependency Injection in .NET](https://blog.ploeh.dk/ref/diidn) that I no longer really remember how this works, but according to it:

> Conceptually, it doesn’t always make much sense to register a string or number as a component in a container. However, with Unity this is at least possible.
>
> Consider, as an example, this constructor:
>
> ```
> public ChiliConCarne(Spiciness spiciness)
> ```
>
> In this example, `Spiciness` is an enum:
>
> ```
> public enum Spiciness
> {
>     Mild = 0,
>     Medium,
>     Hot
> }
> ```
>
> [...]
>
> If you want all consumers of `Spiciness` to use the same value, you can register `Spiciness` and `ChiliConCarne` independently of each other:
>
> ```
> container.RegisterInstance(Spiciness.Medium);
> container.RegisterType<ICourse, ChiliConCarne>();
> ```
>
> When you subsequently resolve `ChiliConCarne` it will have a `Medium` `Spiciness`, as will all other components with a DEPENDENCY on `Spiciness`.

Have you registered the `enum` value with the container?

Comment: Just like you said. But you need to get the enum type and here is my Visual Basic code `container.RegisterInstance(GetType(Spiciness), Spiciness.Medium)`.